# "parentheses not balanced" even though I escaped it?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Im trying to run this simple `sed` command

```
sed '/VALUES\ \([0-9]/d!'
```

It still gives me an error saying `"RE error: parentheses not balanced"` (yes the quotes are there).

What can I do? I mean I could just add another `)` but it wouldn't match my regex.

Comment: Did you maybe forget the 's' in 's/VALUES...' ?

Comment: No, I'm not search replacing.

Comment: @Minix, he is not trying to replace a string, sed does a lot more than that.  `sed /<expression>/d` deletes the lines containing <expression>

Comment: @Marcelo Yeah. Saw that while looking at the man page. Was just a shot in the dark. Seems like I have some be side literature.

Comment: @DisplayName Just add `-r` option to your sed command and move the`!` front of `d` like `sed -r '/VALUES\ \([0-9]/!d'` to avoiding that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The escaped `(` has special meaning in `sed`: it used for [back-references](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq3.html#s3.1.2). To match a literal `(`, simply use it without the backslash: `/VALUES ([0-9]/d!`

If you're attempting to match `\(`, then escape the `\` instead: `\\(`

Escaping the  (space) makes no difference.

Comment: Why? That's not the intuition: escaping is supposed to remove the special meaning of characters. Here, the escaping adds special meaning to a character.

Comment: @MihaiDanila "escaping is supposed to remove the special meaning of characters" - it is? I'm reminded of my CS101 class where the first instance of escaping I ever learned was for using `\n` in C's `printf()`.

Comment: In regular expressions, I thought that relegating a metacharacter to character status was the raison d'être of the backslash. :) BRE turns that on its head, which is exactly what I'm lamenting: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions. And it's inconsistent about it too.

Point being, the moment you have one or more metacharacters introduced without a backslash, you shouldn't have other metacharacters that require the backslash in turn. How does this look? "[" and "\\(" are metacharacters, "\\[" and "(" are not. Poor design IMO.

Comment: On the other hand, `[...]` has no further significance in BRE than being for character classes, but `\(...\)` creates groups to which you can refer to using `\1`, `\2`, etc., and that's pretty much the *only* use for it, so since both creating and refering to the groups use backslashes, in a way it is consistent.

Answer (score 5):

By default, `sed` use [Basic Regular Expression (BRE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03). In BRE, `\(` and `\)` are used for defining [subexpression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06):

> A subexpression can be defined within a BRE by enclosing it between
>   the character pairs "(" and ")". Such a subexpression shall match
>   whatever it would have matched without the "(" and ")", except that
>   anchoring within subexpressions is optional behavior; see BRE
>   Expression Anchoring. Subexpressions can be arbitrarily nested.

Then you can use back-reference expression `'\n'` to match the same (possibly empty) string of characters as was matched by a subexpression enclosed between `\(` and `\)`, where `n` from `1` through `9`. Here, you use only left parentheses `\(`, `sed` can not find right parentheses and raise an error.

In BRE, you just use `(` to match literal left parentheses.

In some `sed` implementations, you can switch to [Extended Regular Expressions (ERE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) (example [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Invoking-sed) with `-r` opstion), so you must use `\(` to match literal left parentheses.

Comment: Why? That's not the intuition: escaping is supposed to remove the special meaning of characters. Here, the escaping adds special meaning to a character.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the reason.  You should not escape the parenthesis in this case.

Single quotes `'` already tells the shell to not bother about the string contents, so it is passed literally to sed.  Escaping the parenthesis is telling sed to expect the ending `\)` as a delimiter for a sub-regex.

Comment: Why? That's not the intuition: escaping is supposed to remove the special meaning of characters. Here, the escaping adds special meaning to a character.